# sum row data in csv file using php

Tags: php, arrays, csv, fgetcsv

I am trying to sum a single row of data(numbers) from a csv file to display the total number using php. this is the csv file I have:

A

0.01
0.1
0.02
0.01
0.02
0.01
0.02

Basically it stretches on. A is basically the first row alphabet in excel.

Basically it stretches on.
I am trying to sum up the row in PHP.

This is my code so far:

```
if (($handle = fopen("file.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
  while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
   $data = array();

   echo array_sum($data);
  }
}
```

My output is basically : 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

I cant seem to figure out why? Could anyone assist me with this?

Comment: Looks like you should be summing the column, not the row

Comment: You overwrite your data with an empty array: `$data = array();   echo array_sum($data);`

Comment: Mark, I think you're right. SteveI see, So how would I go about not overwriting it?

Comment: Got it, all solved! Thanks to Sasi!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try like this

```
<?php
$file = fopen("file.csv","r");
$sum = 0;
while(!feof($file)) {
    $csv = fgetcsv($file,1024);
    if(!$csv[0]){
            print $sum."\n";
    }
    $sum = $sum + $csv[0];
}
```

or declare array before the while loop

```
<?php
$file = fopen("file.csv","r");
$sum = array();
while(!feof($file)) {
    $csv = fgetcsv($file,1024);
    array_push($sum,$csv[0]);
}
echo array_sum($sum)."\n";
```

Comment: Did you get any error or no output at all? i got 0.19
to make it clear try `print $sum."\n";`

Comment: Hey Sasi, thanks for your help.However Nothing is outputted. However when I remove the ! from: `if(!$csv[0])` the output is the whole list of numbers plus the total at the end. However all I only need is for the total sum at the end to be displayed,not the whole thing.

Comment: If `if(!$csv[0])` is the issue then try my updated code, were you can echo array_sum out of while loop